# How to map Data data(Array) ,if data was a value of object

Tags: reactjs

```
const [data,setData]=useState([])
```

i have Received that data as `{results:[20objects],info:{}}`

i have tried console log of  `Object.values(data)`  showing that `[[20 objects],{}]`

i have to do map over that 20 objects Array ?

Answer (score 0):

From your logging `[[20 objects],{}]` it seems that your `data` object is an array and your results array is the 1st element.
So you can access it through `data[0]`.

Then you can map over these 20 objects by using [.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) on your array.

The code should look like this:

```
data[0].map((object) => { //some logic here })
```

Comment: I have tried it showing type error can not read properties of undefined(reading map)

Comment: I edited the answer. From your logging it seems that the `data` is not what you described

Comment: it was type error , it seems that [[20 objects],{}] getting the values from data by object.values

Comment: Can you log the output of the data object?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `data` is `{results:[20objects],info:{}}`:

```
data.results.map((item) => {
    // do stuff here
})
```

or

```
data['results'].map((item) => {
    // do stuff here
})
```